# Excel Formula or Function to Return On-line Status

Tags: function, excel-2010, formula

Does anyone know of a Formula or Function to query the MS Communicator on-line status of a user given their SMTP address (sign-on name)?

I have to occasionally make a number of calls and knowing the user was available would be a big time saver.

Thanks,
WK Cook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office Communicator SDK Wrapper provides various utility functions for things such as contact maintenance, querying presence, as well as other functionality.

http://ocsdkwrapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you.  Not much of a programmer myself but I have friends at work that are.  This could get me to the answer.